# x86/32bit PHP on 64bit Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, 64-bit, 32-bit

This may not be the right place for this question, please point me at the correct SE site if not.

The PHP Documentation for the function `ip2long` states:

> **Note**
>
> Because PHP's integer type is signed, many IP addresses will result in negative integers on 32-bit architectures

Which is fine, however I am little confused if the version of PHP makes a difference?

I am running 64bit Server 2008 with 32bit PHP installed, and I am getting negative integers with some IP addresses. I am clearly running on a 64bit architecture, so this shouldn't be the case according to the (admittedly very vague) documention.

I can only assume that it's because I am running 32bit PHP?? But I can't confirm this anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that it is because you are running a 32-bit build of PHP.  Since it is compiled as a 32-bit application, despite running on a 64-bit system you still do not get 64-bit integers.

It should also be noted that at the time of writing 64-bit builds of PHP on Windows do not provide 64-bit integers (or large file support) so even if you go with a 64-bit version you will still experience integer overflow.

You can try using [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) with the `%u` format to try to get a string representation of the 64-bit number.  I used this code with older PHP4 applications running on 32-bit where I wanted to print out a 64-bit integer.  Note that it may not be suitable if you need to do anything other than output the 64-bit number.

```
$string = sprintf('%u', $someBigInteger);
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming this for me. using `sprintf('%u', $someBigInteger);` does solve my issue and the resulting integer can still be converted back to a dotted IP address using long2ip.